I want to copy and paste in Chrome. but doesn't work. How can I fix it?
I'm trying to copy and paste a sentence in Chrome, but doesn't work.
So I tried F12, and "Disable JavaScript".
But, when I press the X button to exit from the F12 menu, the copy-paste function stops working again. How can I fix this?

You can try using special extensions for Chrome. For example this one https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/enable-copy-paste-ecp/fpjppnhnpnknbenelmbnidjbolhandnf
